# What phrase is this?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

**Hearing the noise**, the boy woke up.

According to its use which phrase is this?

Comment: It's not a phrase but, as equin0x80 says, a non-finite clause. Its function is that of supplementary adjunct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's a "non-finite clause". Can you make your question more interesting?